# FFT of large data (16gB) using Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, fft, large-data

I am trying to compute a fast fourier transform of a large chunk of data imported from a text file which is around 16 gB in size. I was trying to think of a way to compute its fft in matlab, but due to my computer memory (8gB) it is giving me an out of memory error. I tried using memmap, textscan, but was not able to apply to get FFT of the combined data.

Can anyone kindly guide me as to how should I approach to get the fourier transform? I am also trying to get the fourier transform (using definition) using C++ code on a remote server, but it's taking a long time to execute. Can anyone give me a proper insight as to how should I handle this large data?

Comment: Either try to split up the data in smaller chunk, so your computer can handle it, or get more memory.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But splitting the data in smaller chunks would make it difficult to apply the FFT. The FFT needs access to all data

Comment: Are you implementing your own FFT or are you using the built-in fft function fft(x)?

Comment: I would *really* love to know what you're going to do with that FFT?

Comment: I am using the in built fft function for now. But I can try and build my own fft, my concern is that fft would need to access all data, thus how can I handle it here?

Comment: I am trying to get some insight into origins of flicker noise, thus need to compute this fft of the data generated.

Comment: The swap memory is supposed to get you enough memory but it will probably slow down the fft compared to a divide and conquer implementation. Moreover you may not have enough swap memory (then use a large swap file? `mkswap`).

Comment: @user3821417: Do you **really** want a FFT with billions of points? Because usually on longer signals you calculate a spectrogram (which is just calculating the FFT repeatedly over short intervals)

Comment: Have you considered using a distributed memory parallelization? If you have access to two machines with 8GB each then you can use FFTW with MPI to calculate this transform. You mentined you have access to a remote machine, does it have enough RAM? If so, you don't need to write your own C++ code, use the fftw library which is fast and can be parallelized to use all the remote machine's cores, if available to you.

Comment: @MSalters just as an example of the application look at [this](http://research.colfaxinternational.com/file.axd?file=2012%2F2%2FColfax_Benchmark_Large_1D_FFTW_NUMA.pdf). The application is to search for pulsars, and the data they talk about in that paper is anywhere from 2^29 to 2^33. I don't know about OP's application, but sometimes taking FFT of a large data set is needed.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the resolution of the FFT that you require. If you only need an FFT of, say, 1024 points, then you can reshape your data to, or sequentially read it as `N x 1024` blocks. Once you have it in this format, you can then add the output of each FFT result to a 1024 point complex accumulator.

If you need the same resolution after the FFT, then you need more memory, or a special `fft` routine that is not included in Matlab (but I'm not sure if it is even mathematically possible to do a partial FFT by buffering small chunks through for full resolution).

Comment: Thank you, can you kindly elaborate on this, I was not quite able to get what you meant. I am quite new to matlab, thank you

Answer (score 2):

It may be better you implement FFT with your own code.

The FFT algorithm has a "[butterfly](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/DIT-FFT-butterfly.png)" operation. Hence you can split the whole step into smaller blocks.

The file size is too large for a typical pc to handle. But FFT doesn't need *all* data at once. It can always start with 2-point (maybe 8-point is better) FFT, and you can build up by cascading the stages. It means you can [read only a few points](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-large-text-files.html) at a time, do some calculation, and *save* your data to disk. Next time you doing another iteration, you can read the saved data from disk.

Depending on how you build the data structure, you can either store all the data in one single file, and read/save it with pointers (in Matlab it's merely a number); or you can store every single point in one individual file, generating billions of files and distinguishing them by file names.

The idea is you can dump your calculation to disk, instead of memory. Of course it requires such amount of disk space, which is more feasible.

---

I can show you a piece of pseudo-code. Depending on the data structure of your original data (that 16GB txt file), the implementation will be different, but you can easily operate as you own the file. I will start with 2-point FFT and do with the 8-point sample in [this wikipedia picture](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DIF_DIT.jpg).

1.Do 2-point FFT on `x`, generating `y`, the 3rd column of white circles from left.

> ```
> read x[0], x[4] from file 'origin'
> y[0] = x[0] + x[4]*W(N,0);
> y[1] = x[0] - x[4]*W(N,0);
> save y[0], y[1] to file 'temp'
> remove x[0], x[4], y[0], y[1] from memory
> read x[2], x[6] from file 'origin'
> y[2] = x[2] + x[6]*W(N,0);
> y[3] = x[2] - x[6]*W(N,0);
> save y[2], y[3] to file 'temp'
> remove x[2], x[6], y[2], y[3] from memory
> ....
> ```

2.Do 2-point FFT on `y`, generating `z`, the 5th column of white circles.

3.Do 2-point FFT on `z`, generating final result, `X`.

Basically the [Cooley–Tukey FFT algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm) is designed to enable you cut up the data and calculate piece by piece, so it's possible to handle large-amount data. I know it's not a regular way but if you can take a look at the Chinese version of that Wikipedia page, you may find a number of pictures that may help you understand how it splits up the points.

Comment: Thank you Yvon, I am still no clear as to how would I segregate data, apply fft, recombine them. Can you kindly illustrate an example for this?

Comment: I showed you the first iteration, from x to y. You can do the following iters similarly.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this same problem. I ended up finding a solution in a paper:
[Extending sizes of effective convolution algorithms](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/83060). It essentially involves loading shorter chunks, multiplying by a phase factor and FFT-ing, then loading the next chunk in the series. This gives a sampled of the total FFT of the full signal. The process is then repeated with a number of times with different phase factors to fill in the remaining points. I will attempt to summarize here (adapted from Table II in the paper):

1. For a total signal `f(j)` of length `N`, decide on a number `m` or shorter chunks each of length `N/m` that you can store in memory (if needed, zero-pad the signal such that `N` is a multiple of `m`)
2. For `beta = 0, 1, 2, ... ,m - 1` do the following:
3. Divide the new series into `m` subintervals of `N/m` successive points.
4. For each subinterval, multiply each jth element by `exp(i*2*pi*j*beta/N)`. Here, `j` is indexed according to the position of the point relative to the first in the whole data stream.
5. Sum the first elements of each subinterval to produce a single number, sum the second elements, and so forth. This can be done as points are read from file, so there is no need to have the full set of `N` points in memory.
6. Fourier transform the resultant series, which contains `N/m` points.
7. This will give `F(k)` for `k = ml + beta`, for `l = 0, ..., N/m-1`. Save these values to disk.
8. Go to 2, and proceed with the next value of `beta`.